# In a forward bias diode, why do electrons continue into neighboring holes?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

When an electron from the n-type side fills a hole on the p-type side, it fills the valence shell. For reference, consider this video: https://youtu.be/7ukDKVHnac4?t=230. I learned in chemistry that atoms like this. So why do the electrons continue into neighboring holes if they are already part of a filled valence shell? I understand that part of it is from the electric potential of the battery attracting the electrons into neighboring holes. Is that it?

Comment: Simplifications of what really need quantum mechanics to understand properly tend not to work too well. You may have to be content with some very hand-wavy approximations. Just to adjust your expectations down before you get too frustrated with the unsatisfactory answers to come.

Comment: Electrons are dislocated in any kind of conductor, that's what makes the magic of electrical current possible. They are like a pile of paper dropped to the ground in a breeze. If you are lucky and your ground has some holes or bumps in it, you may be able to catch some sheets (electrons) there.

Comment: Compared to the mass of an electron, the electric fields are much stronger.

Comment: Remember that each side of the diode is electrically neutral; if you add an electron to a valence shell (which fills the shell), it is no longer electrically neutral so an electric field exists.